# Read from Device-File gives additional input

Tags: c++, linux-device-driver, inputstream, barcode-scanner

I connect a QR-Code-Scanner to my Linux-PC over USB in USB-COM-Mode.
When I do so, a file is created: /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Datalogic_ADC__Inc._Handheld_Barcode_Scanner_S_N_E18C59366.-if00

I read from this file like so:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <fstream>      
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
        while (1) {
                ifstream bufferLink("/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Datalogic_ADC__Inc._Handheld_Barcode_Scanner_S_N_E18C59366.-if00");
                if (bufferLink.is_open()) {
                        string line;
                        while (!bufferLink.eof()) {
                                cout << "Waiting for input: " << endl;
                                getline(bufferLink, line);
                                cout << "+++++++++ Line: " << line << endl;
                        }
                }
        }
        usleep(1000*1000);
        return 0;
}
```

I then created a QR-Code with the Data: Andre Mantei ist der Beste.

But when I read the QR-Code with my Scanner it gives me a lot of additional output:

```
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: Andre Mantei ist der Beste.
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line:  
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line:  
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}
Waiting for input: 
+++++++++ Line: 
Waiting for input:
```

It happens not always but most of the time. 
Can anyone explain that behavior ?

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: Do you have a manual about the protocol your scanner uses?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 that is a problem, but it's not the problem

Comment: In the manuel it says: USB COM to simulate RS232 standard interface